# Solving system of equations with $3$ variables:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I am looking for some detail about how the following system of equations is solved, I checked using wolfram and got the answer but I am not sure the details of how to get there.

$$x+y=1$$ $$xw+y=\frac{1}{2}$$ $$xw^2+y = \frac{1}{3}$$

and the solution is $w = \frac{1}{3}, x = \frac{3}{4}, y = \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Plug first equation into second and third to get 2 by 2 I'm $x,w$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the first equation, you get that $y=1-x$. So, you now have only two equations:$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}xw-x=-\frac12\\xw^2-x=-\frac23,\end{array}\right.$$which is equivalent to$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x(w-1)=-\frac12\\x(w-1)(w+1)=-\frac23.\end{array}\right.$$But now, dividing the second equality by the first one gives you $w+1=\frac43$. So…

Comment: so then $w = 1/3$ then plug it into the second equation you have there to find $x$? or the first one too

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: when you say but now dividng the second equality by the first could you show details of that?

Comment: $$\frac{x(w-1)(w+1)}{x(w-1)}=\frac{-2/3}{-1/2}\iff w+1=\frac43.$$

Comment: and then after this I can plug x into y = 1 -x to find y?

Comment: Yes, that is correct too.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it is very clear and helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the second equation from the first equation
\begin{eqnarray*}
x(1-w)=\frac{1}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
Subtract the third equation from the second equation
\begin{eqnarray*}
xw(1-w)=\frac{1}{6}
\end{eqnarray*}
So $w=?$ ....